# Update if two or more data and skip if data is not there in single query with laravel eloquont

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have an array with table data, I need to check rows and if any data have two or more same data I need to update them and skip other data. I have done this by using two foreach and it's getting my query very slow.

```
          foreach ($vehicles as $key => $value) {
            $exists = DB::table('vehicles')
                ->where('site', $value->site)
                ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                ->get('id');

            if ($exists->count() > 1) {
                $duplicate = 1;
                foreach ($exists as $exist) {
                    DB::table('vehicles')
                        ->where('id', $exist->id)
                        ->update([
                            'duplicate_entry' => $duplicate,
                        ]);
                }
            }
```

I have one solution that I can add `upsert` method for the second loop, I need to know is there any way to do this in a single query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Eloquent model

Work flow:-

You can simply get the conditional record's ides in array ( Now you have an array of ides) and then use **whereIn()** to update multiple records which belongs to that ides at ones.

```
foreach ($vehicles as $key => $value){ 
  $exists = Vehicle::where('site', $value->site)
     ->whereNull('deleted_at')
     ->pluck('id')->toArray();
    
  if (count($exists) > 1) {
      $duplicate = 1;
      Vehicle::whereIn('id', $exists)
             ->update(['duplicate_entry' => $duplicate]);
  }
 }
```

Comment: this is not working because in `$exists` array is an object array. need to convert it to array with only including `id` values

Comment: You just need to use pluck('id') instead of get ('id')
I have updated the code.